# How to keep powershell notification in action center

Tags: powershell, push-notification, notifications, windows-10

I have this powershell script to send a notification which works great, except for the fact that it is not saved in the notification center. It times out, and fades away, but it is not there when you click the notifications button on the right of the taskbar. Is there anything I could add to my script to make it happen? Thanks!

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "icoOnline.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "None" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "wzzup this is a title." 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "WHATS UPPP THIS IS A PARAGRAPH!"

$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

Comment: Look at using toast notifications instead of winforms, it is the newer standard. Search google, GitHub or psgallery for a module that already does it or an example like [this](https://gist.github.com/loge5/7ec41e2e2f0e0293fdcc5155499e9072). [This](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BurntToast/0.6.1) module seems to be the most popular.

Comment: thanks @jkdba I'll give that a go.

Comment: That still did not show up in the action center after it appeared.

Comment: My script does use toast notifications... as of Windows 10 Toast and Windforms are the same.

Comment: In my case it did persistant in action center, only disappeared after I hover my cursor over the notification icon in taskbar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a while condition to make it last. But again dont make the script hold permanently. Instead you can create a background job for the same.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
while($True)
{
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "wzzup this is a title." 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "WHATS UPPP THIS IS A PARAGRAPH!"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
Start-Sleep 500
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case it did persistant, only disappeared after I hover my cursor over the notification icon in taskbar.